# What's the purpose of the operator $(\Delta^{-1}+\lambda)^{-1}$ in Tomita-Takesaki modular theory?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, von-neumann-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

I was reading Tomita-Takesaki modular theory (from all the books, and articles), the goal is to relate a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{A}$ with its commutant $\mathcal{A}'$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ as 'seen' by a cyclic, and separating vector, say $\Omega$.

I have so far read all the stuff about the operator
$$S: A\Omega\mapsto A^*\Omega$$

Then surprisingly for each $A\in \mathcal{A}$, and $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}_+$,
$$(SS^*+\lambda)^{-1}A\in \mathcal{A}'$$

I can follow the logic in the proofs, but this relation is quite surprising, and I was wondering what is the heuristics/intuition behind this relation. This looks like resolvent type thing, but after spending weeks I still can't seem to figure out the motivation/intuition behind this or how someone would have figured it out.